# sh script to rotate logs periodically

Tags: shell, cron

I would like to create a sh script which can run the following command via cron periodically

00 01 * * * /usr/local/sbin/rotatenginxlogs.sh > dev/null 2>&1

how should i write the sh script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a cron job to rotate `nginx` logs, you should investigate using [`logrotate` utility](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) to do the same.

From the man page:

> Logrotate allows automatic rotation, compression, removal, and mailing of log files.  Each log file may be handled daily, weekly, monthly, or when it grows too large.

That way, you won't need to use cron jobs. Check `/etc/logrotate.d`, there in the `nginx` file, you will have to setup configuration. Check [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-manage-log-files-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-12-10) on setting up the same

Comment: Do i still need to use crontab to run the logrotate regularly if i use logrotate?